# How to hold reference to Context Object in Android Library

Tags: android, android-library, android-context

I'm trying to make my first android library as a practice. This a wrapper for `Google Cloud Messaging`

Suppose this code is called anywhere in Android application:

```
GCMLib.initialize(this);
```

This method accepts Context as parameter. Later on Library receives a new `Push` in a `BroadcastReceiver` (Introduced in Manifest),  I'm trying to create a `Notification` there, and retrieve target application's Icon and AppName String using that `Context`.

So far I'm holding a reference to `Context` object in an static helper class:

```
public final class HelperClass {
private static Context appContext;

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return appContext;
}

public static void setAppContext(Context appContext) {
    HelperClass.appContext = appContext;
}
}
```

What is the standard pattern for android Library projects ?

Comment: I have been told that it can cause memory leaks to have a static Context variable, so it's recommended to obtain a reference to the ApplicationContext whenever possible (Except in some specific cases like inflation of Fragment view, for that the inflater has its own Context), without making it static.

Answer (score 1):

If the Context does not need to draw UI or the like, that is, application context is enough, you could do something like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{

    private MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.instance = this;
    }

    public MyApplication getApplication() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Now you can invoke `MyApplication.getApplication()` for a valid Context. This will not cause leaks as Application is a Singleton (only one instance of Application will exist).

To make use of the custom Application object you will need to update the manifest, see this link for an example: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Answer (score 0):

extending the Context from an Application is not a good idea. It's not assured that the context is not null. If you have a Service you should/may want to use the services context. Means:

```
onStartCommand() {
   if (aSingleTonObject.getContext() == null) {      
      this.aSingleTonObject.setContext(this);
 }
 return START_STICKY; 
}

public class aSingleTonClass {
private static Context context = null; 
public static getContext() {
  if (this.context == null) { 
  //assure that the service is still running and run it if not
    startService(...);
  }
}
}
```

Keeping a reference in the extends Application class is never a good idea. Create your own factory if you want lazyloading.